# Is there any way to allow access only to files previously listed in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, server

I need the server to only allow access to three files (`index.php`, `estilo.css` and `scripts.js`), and deny access to any other file type in the directory.
I think the easiest way to do this would be through `.htaccess`. But if there is another way...

Comment: Move the other files outside of your web server's document root. The web server won't serve them but they'll still be accessible via PHP.

Comment: Let's say I have no autonomy (control) over the other files. I need exactly what I have described, only allow the execution of the files I list.
If it were something so easy (move the other files), obviously I would have solved it. But thank you for your attention.

Comment: What would be the downfall to using an `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Because I do not know I see another way to do it. 
And as far as I know, .htaccess file is responsible for most of the server's security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.htaccess` you can deny access to all files and then specifically allow access just to these three files. However, exactly how you do this depends on whether you are using Apache 2.4+ or an earlier version of Apache.

On Apache 2.4+

```
Require all denied
<FilesMatch "^(index\.php|estilo\.css|scripts\.js)$">
    Require all granted
</FilesMatch>
```

On Apache 2.2

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "^(index\.php|estilo\.css|scripts\.js)$">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```